# while changing directory in os python 2 program stops running in next itiration

Tags: python, loops, input, directory, pycharm

I've got a python 2 script which does only work on the first loop. It will stop working on next loop.

**Just not working like I´m expectig it - no error messages.**

---

This is the used code:
[image]

Comment: Agree with @khelwood.

Comment: Next time please paste your code into a short codeblock or directly into a code-snipped

Comment: Please also clarify what "stops working" means. There is no error message in your picture.

Comment: it was not taking second input.while second time at the end of the loop where "raw_input" is used it stops. maybe because of after changing the directory it can not find the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot be sure without actually being able to try it (via copy and paste) it looks like a problem with "before", and where you have placed the `raw_input()`.

If you placed the `raw_input()` in the loop straight after the while loop you could remove the `raw_input` outside of your code and only use one.

Second since the value of `before` never actually clears the `else` statement always executes.  This means you keep adding the filepath held in `before` to `os.chdir()` (line 13) returning an error.

At the end of the `while` loop you should clear `before` (i.e. `before = ""`)